# App has more downloads then it does users

Tags: ios, firebase, app-store-connect, firebase-analytics

iTunes connect has reported 19 downloads within the past 10 days. While firebase is only reporting 1 new user. Is this something to worry about? I'm using anonymous authentication with firebase and the users are created automatically on the initial app launch.

Comment: Users may have automatic download turned on on their other devices. They download and launch the app on one device. On other devices it downloads automatically but they don't run it?

Comment: @Paulw11 I suppose that could explain some of it. However I had 7 downloads yesterday according to iTunes connect from 2 separate territories and only 1 new firebase user.

Comment: It could also be the delay in iTunes reporting; it is based on UTC AFAIK

Comment: @Paulw11 That doesn't explain why firebase is lagging so far behind. Digging deeper iTunes connect reports 19 downloads in the past 10 days and firebase only reports 1 new user.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the case that 15 people deleted the application after downloading it. This makes sense because it would be strange to decrease the download count after losing a user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Users do not get deleted from firebase when they delete the app. At least not in my app.